# Trying to get data from this site into google sheets using app script

Tags: api, google-sheets

Could anyone help me with the code to convert responses from this site
https://services.sia.homeoffice.gov.uk/PublicRegister/

I need it to read a license number from google sheets - example:
1012894854698842

And populate results into the same spreadsheet

I've been playing around with both postman and website scrapers but still can't figure it out

Please Help!!
Thank You

```
function senddatatoform() {

var url =   'https://services.sia.homeoffice.gov.uk/PublicRegister/SearchPublicRegisterByLicence'; // this is the 'request url' as shown in your browser (not always the url of the form).  

var payload = {
 LicenseNo: "1012894854698842",
 
}//continue with all required post data   

var options = {
method: "POST",
payload: payload
}

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);
/*this is where what you need to do next might vary -- if you're looking for a 'success' page, you might write some code here to verify that the http response is correct based on your needs.
*/ 

const content = response.getContentText();

const regEx = /<div class="ax_h5">\s*(\S+)/g; 
while (match = regEx.exec(content)) {
console.log(match[1]);
}

};
Logger.log
```

The Information I require is

First name

Surname

Licence number

Role

Licence sector

Expiry date

Status

Status explanation

Additional licence conditions

The license number is in a spreadsheet for each employee

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far. See[how do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```js
function senddatatoform() {
  const colId = 1;
  const colOutput = 2;
  const rowStart = 2;
  const cols = 9;
  
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const rows = sheet.getLastRow() - rowStart + 1;
  const ids = sheet.getRange(rowStart, colId, rows, 1).getValues();
  const values = new Array(rows);
  for (let i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
    const data = getData(ids[i][0]);
    if (!data) { values[i] = new Array(cols); }
    else { values[i] = data; }
  }
  
  sheet.getRange(rowStart, colOutput, rows, cols).setValues(values);
  
  function getData(id) {
    const url = 'https://services.sia.homeoffice.gov.uk/PublicRegister/SearchPublicRegisterByLicence';
    const payload = {
      'LicenseNo': id,
    };
    var options = {
      'method': 'POST',
      'payload': payload
    };
    const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
    const content = response.getContentText();
    const result = content.match(/panel-default">([\s\S]+)<div class="footer/);
    if (!result) { return; }
    const regex = /form-group[\s\S]*?<(?:div|span).*?>([^<>]+)<\/(?:div|span)/g
    const matches = [...result[1].matchAll(regex)];
    if (matches.length === 0) { return; }
    const values = matches.map(match => match[1].trim());
    return values;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank You 
I require all the information it gives back how do I add more data to return

Comment: Also how do I add this to a spreadsheet? thank you

Comment: Please investigate the pattern of the information and do [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match). You can write with [appendRow](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendRow(Object))

Comment: Sorry I still don't understand how to do this, I need all the information the form returns 
with the SIA number being a variable to search

Comment: Please edit your question to tell clearly the expected input, output, and specifically which part process you want to ask for a code.

Comment: I have added what I have so far and the information I need in a spreadsheet

Comment: How is the license number stored in the sheet? You are asking for how to insert values to spreadsheet, so please add it. In what way do you want to insert it?

Comment: Updated. Please try it.

Comment: I still get the same response in Logger. I dont receive the date and active status

Comment: What do you mean by same response? It works for me. See my screenshot.

Comment: It doesnt paste the date in the active sheet for me

Answer (score 0):

May be improved ...

```
function senddatatoform() {
  var url = 'https://services.sia.homeoffice.gov.uk/PublicRegister/SearchPublicRegisterByLicence'; 
    var payload = {
    LicenseNo: "1012894854698842",
  }
  var options = {
    method: "POST",
    payload: payload
  }

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);

  Logger.log(response.getContentText().replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r|\t|  )/gm,"").match(/<div class="panel-body">.*<div class="footer">/g)[0].replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"|").replace(/(\|)+/gm,"\n"))
}
```